# Booting ubuntu desktop into command prompt

Tags: networking, command-line, server, battery, power-management

I use ubuntu desktop 10.10 on a netbook. Quite often I use it as a proxy server (squid3) and file server (samba) for my network. So when I am using it as a network server, is it possible to boot into only command prompt and there by I can bring down power usage and have a longer battery backup.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can edit the kernel parameters in grub to add `text` as a boot parameter.

To do that temporarily (just for the current boot), you can edit the boot menu entry by pressing `e` (if you don't want the default boot menu entry, first select the one you want).  If you don't see the boot menu, you can hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key during boot to make sure it gets shown.  You have to add the word `text` at the end of the line that starts with `linux`.

To make this permanent, you can add `text` to the value of `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub`.  If you didn't change that file before (some people remove the `quiet` and/or `splash`, or add other kernel options), the line will then look like:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash text"
```

After changing this, you should run `sudo update-grub` to regenerate the actual grub boot menu configuration.

---

When you want to start the GUI from the console, do it with:

```
sudo start gdm
```

To stop the GUI again, log out (to make sure all your settings are stored etc.), switch to the console, and do the same with "stop" instead of "start":

```
sudo stop gdm
```

Comment: You've got the right answer here, but a couple of lines about how to get the GRUB menu to show up (tap esc at the right time) and how to edit the boot line would make it much more useful. I can't remember the exact steps or I'd post them here, but you guys are way more guru than me!!

Comment: I also just remembered I forgot to add how to make it permanent, so was going to edit it anyway...  ;-)

Answer (score -2):

I dont know if you can boot into shell, w/o the graphics mode, but you can use the 6 terminals *Nix provides, buy pressing

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>F6</kbd>